# Mocking the function of a separate class

Tags: php, phpunit

I have function test which return the repsonse of static function staticABC that belongs to separate class

```
function test()
{
   return testA::staticABC();
}
```

Now I want to write PHPUnit cases for function test by mocking staticABC() function.Can any techie have idea about this ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way of mocking a function, but what you could do is use some kind of [test double](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_double):

```
class SUT{
    $staticCreator = array('testA::staticABC'); //Initialized to a default 
             //for production, would be better if injected somehow before using

    function setStaticCreator($staticCreator){
        $this->staticCreator=$staticCreator;
    }
    function test(){
        return call_user_func($this->staticCreator);
    }
}
```

and then run your test this way:

```
class Test extends ...{
    function mockStaticABC(){
        return "mock_string";
    }

    test_testfunction(){
        $sut = new SUT();
        $staticCreator = array($this,'mockStaticABC');
        $sut->setStaticCreator($staticCreator);
        $mock_return = $sut->test();
        $this->assertEquals("mock_string",$mock_return);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Alex, thx for reply , but not got your point ..Sorry can you represent this with other simple way

Comment: +1 but some nitpicking: this is using a factory but it's not DI *(afaik)*. Using DI, the object would have been passed to the function to operate on. This is far easier done if the language supports interfaces *(I have no clue about php)* and makes the dependency between the function and the object explicit to the ones using the function.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers yes, it is not DI. I will update it to Doubling.